# Change Calculator Subtracting One

Tags: java, calculator, netbeans-8

My calculator in Java will not output the correct amount of change. It subtracts one penny and I am not sure why.

I initially declared the change as separate variables but I then just multiplied the users input by 100, but I still have the same problem.

```
//this is where the variables are declared
double penny = 0.01;
double nickel = 0.05;
double dime = 0.10;
double quarter = 0.25;
double half_dollar = 0.50;
double dollar_coin = 1.00;

double user_input = 0;

int total_penny, total_nickel, total_dime, total_quarter, 
total_half_dollar, total_dollar_coin;

Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

//this is where the user can input data
System.out.println("What amount would you like change for: ");
user_input = in.nextDouble();

//this is where the users data will be processed
total_dollar_coin = (int) (user_input / 1.0);
user_input = user_input % 1.00;
total_half_dollar = (int) (user_input / 0.50);
user_input = user_input % 0.50;
total_quarter = (int) (user_input / 0.25);
user_input = user_input % 0.25;
total_dime = (int) (user_input / 0.10);
user_input = user_input % 0.10;
total_nickel = (int) (user_input / 0.05);
user_input = user_input % 0.01;
total_penny = (int) (user_input / 0.01);

//this is where the information will be outputted to the user
System.out.println("Your change will be: " + total_dollar_coin + " dollar 
coin(s) ");
System.out.println(total_half_dollar + " half dollar coin(s) " + 
total_quarter 
+ " quarter(s) ");
System.out.print(total_dime + " dime(s) " + total_nickel + " nickel(s) " + 
total_penny + " penny (or pennies) ");
    }
```

}

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: (A) Strip down your code and data to one minimal example of input-output-expectation. (B) Never use `double`/`Double` or `float`/`Float` for money or anywhere else [if you want accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems).

Comment: Don't use floating-point for money. It isn't precise, as you have discovered. Use`BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug this, you will see that for e.g. `51.43` your last line:

```
total_penny = (int) (user_input / 0.01);
```

results in something like:

[image]

Since you are casting to **int**, this will result in "unexpected output", in this case **zero (0)** - see link provided above in the second comment regarding accuracy. 
Nonetheless, a possible solution to the problem (as an educational exercise) is to do the following:

```
BigDecimal total_penny;
int total_nickel, total_dime, total_quarter, total_half_dollar, total_dollar_coin;
```

And then in your `total_penny` line:

```
user_input = user_input % 0.05;    --> you have 0.01 typo here
total_penny = BigDecimal.valueOf(user_input / 0.01);
```

Format the `total_penny` output and output that:

```
String penny = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(total_penny);
System.out.println("..." + penny + " penny (or pennies) ");
```

This will give you the amount you expect:

[image]

Comment: No. All the division and modulus operations should be done via `BigDecimal.divide()/.modulus()`, not in floating point. Otherwise the original problem remains. There are redundant parentheses in this expression.

Comment: @user207421 You are correct, yet for this problem converting everything to BigDecimal feels like an overkill...?